# Looking for a good phonegap tutorial for the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, cordova

I am looking for a good Phonegap tutorial for the iphone. I am a beginner and before diving into the various javascript functions it uses I need to learn how to structure the divs on the page.

Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out my blog. I have started a phonegap tutorial series - http://hiediutley.com/

Comment: Blog having old contents..updation needed!

Answer (score 0):

The [Phonegap wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials) has a bunch of tutorials. This page has all tutorials for iOS, Android, and all the rest as well. Here is the tutorial for [Xcode 4](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-iOS-using-Xcode-4) and [Xcode 3](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494778/Getting+Started+with+PhoneGap+%28iOS%29+-+Xcode+3).

Answer (score 0):

My co-worker just wrote a tutorial for how to get started PhoneGap with a simple demo. It might help to get you started with it. Check it out here: http://keyholesoftware.com/2013/03/25/introduction-to-phonegap/

Good luck!

Comment: The community frowns on overt self-promotion (which isn't the case currently) and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam - with that in mind, remember that you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers. Take a look at the [FAQ on Promoting](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 0):

Two good tutorials I found very helpful were these:-

[Ray Wenderlich Blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30734/phonegap-tutorial-a-cross-platform-zombie-app)
and
[Mobile Tuts plus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-from-scratch/)